# How to calculate the average of only one column in a series of file with python?

Tags: python, average, series

I have a series of file( with format shown in below) with different names such as:
100107_902988_6188DAAXX_s_6.sorted
100107_902988_6188DAAXX_s_7.sorted
(if you notice only the part 6 and 7 are different in the file name)

[image]

I would like to have the average of the last column with numbers (column number 8 the one which start with 15) for all these files! if possible in a text file such as:
100107_902988_6188DAAXX_s_6.sorted : 15 (or what ever the average is)
100107_902988_6188DAAXX_s_7.sorted : 17

I tried with the data.split command and then using e[7] column but I got the average of each line!!!! such as 3 for 15 (which I assume that my script made the 1+5/2)
I wonder if someone can help me
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but something like this should do the trick:

```
import glob

def avg(lst):
    return float(sum(lst))/len(lst)

all_numbers = []
for filename in glob.glob("100107_902988_6188DAAXX_s_*.sorted"):
    numbers = []
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            numbers.append(int(line.split()[7]))
    print "{0}: {1:.2f}".format(filename, avg(numbers))
    all_numbers.extend(numbers)
print "Total average: {0:.2f}".format(avg(all_numbers))
```

Comment: thanks! but there are some difficulties that I have! the first thing is that the last line dose not run and I get a SyntaxError: invalid syntax!! but when I run it with out the last line I get the number for each file! as I understand the last one is to have an average of all the file? (so it's not necessary for me) but still I get a very low number ( around 3 and I was expecting to get around 10)! is there any way that I can test it to know if it's calculating the right number? I tried to make a file with similar format which I know the average but when I run it I get  list index out of range

Comment: @Mahmood Try inserting debugging `print` statements in strategic places to see what numbers it is actually working on. E.g. in the `avg` function, do `print lst` and `print sum(lst), len(lst)`. I'm guessing it is somehow adding lots of `0` items to the list, or something like that.